# Doctrine with MSSQL returning same children

Tags: sql-server, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am using an existing MSSQL-database (Dynamics) and to fetch data out of it I've cloned the database layout in a Doctrine entity so I can fetch the data out of the database. This works well for a sole entity, but when I have OneToMany relationships, something goes wrong. It's returning the correct amount of children, but they're all the same.

When I copy paste the runnable query into SQL Server I get the correct results (with different children). So the SQL query is good.

So it seems like Doctrine doesn't hydrate the result correctly. I am using the pdo_sqlsrv driver and Doctrine2 with Symfony 2.8.

Dynamics table layout:

```
PurchTable
recid = unique integer
purchid = unique string

PurchLine
recid = unique integer
purchid = referring to purchid from PurchTable
itemid = string
etc...
```

PurchTable Entity:

```
 /**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="recid", type="integer")
 */
private $recid;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="purchid", type="string", length=255)
 * @ORM\Id
 */
private $orderid;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="PurchLine", mappedBy="order")
 */
protected $lines;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->lines = new ArrayCollection();
}
```

PurchLine:

```
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="recid", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 */
private $recid;

/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="linenum", type="integer")
 */
private $linenum;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="itemid", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $itemid;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="PurchTable", inversedBy="lines")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="purchid", referencedColumnName="purchid")
 */
protected $order;
```

As you can see I changed the property name to orderid in PurchTable to avoid using the same name, but that didn't help.

So what am I doing wrong? :)

I cannot change the driver at a short time so I am wondering if this is a driver issue or not (to change the priority of changing the driver). After reading this:

http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/configuration.html#driver

A Microsoft SQL Server driver that uses pdo_sqlsrv PDO Note that this driver caused problems in our tests. Prefer the sqlsrv driver if possible.

I am wondering if the pdo_sqlsrv driver can cause these issues or not.

### edit

I tested the sqlsrv driver (be sure to use an empty string as username instead of null (for pdo_sqlsrv) to use Windows Authentication) and I encounter the same problem. So it must be something in Doctrine or in the relationship.

### edit 2

I recreated the entities to avoid any spelling mistakes but to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in the wrong definition of the columns. The RecId column in the MSSQL database was a bigint instead of integer.

So, changing

```
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="recid", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 */
private $recid;
```

to

```
/**
 * @var bigint
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="recid", type="bigint")
 * @ORM\Id
 */
private $recid;
```

is the answer.